# Getting Linestring coordinates for roads using OSM

Tags: javascript, node.js, leaflet, gis, openstreetmap

[image]

I'm trying to get the road network in an area focusing on the smaller (1-2 lane ) roads using osm and node. Using the OSM overpass api, I used the following query:

```
const roadsOverpassQuery = `
[out:json];
(way[lanes=1](${bbox}); way[lanes=2](${bbox}); );
out;
`;
```

I was able to get  many of the roads within a bounding box. I noticed that these roads when converted to geojson objects have nodes

```
 {
"_id": {
  "$oid": "643c3fd883215e96ece3be0a"
 {,
"type": "way",
"id": 5053100,
"nodes": [
  33979706,
  33979705
],
"tags": {
  "adot_name": "Tucson-Benson Highway",
  "bicycle": "yes",
  "hgv": "designated",
  "highway": "motorway",
  "lanes": "2",
  "maxspeed": "75 mph",
  "old_ref": "US 80 (old AZ 86)",
  "oneway": "yes",
  "ref": "I 10"
}
```

I passed these into the overpass api using

```
const overpassQuery = `
[out:json];
(
  ${nodeIds.map(id => `node(${id})`).join(';')};
);
out;
```

`;

These as geojson look like:

```
"features": [
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": "node/33979705",
    "properties": {
      "highway": "motorway_junction",
      "ref": "292",
      "id": "node/33979705"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        -110.5123291,
        31.9766748
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "type": "Feature",
    "id": "node/33979706",
    "properties": {
      "id": "node/33979706"
    },
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [
        -110.5141282,
        31.9773252
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

I notice that the geometry type is point. In other places I've seen roads made up of Linestrings:

```
{
"type": "Feature",
"geometry": {
"type": "LineString",
"coordinates": [
  [-122.483696, 37.833818],
  [-122.483482, 37.833174],
  [-122.483396, 37.8327],
  [-122.483568, 37.832056],
  [-122.48404, 37.831141],
  [-122.48404, 37.830497],
  [-122.483482, 37.82992],
  [-122.483568, 37.829548],
  [-122.48507, 37.828802],
  [-122.4861, 37.828387],
  [-122.486958, 37.828138],
  [-122.487001, 37.827885]
 ]
},
"properties": {
"name": "Example LineString"
}
}
```

How do I get the Linestring coordinates for the roads of interest?

Comment: According to [this comment](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/78529/best-way-to-get-coordinates-of-each-node-of-a-way/78582), you can use the geometry operator in a convert statement. Using the way ID in your question, the query would look like this: `[out:json]; way(5053100); convert item ::=::,::geom=geom(),_osm_type=type(); out geom;` [Here's an example](https://tsplay.dev/mA8ZQN). Does that address your question? If so, I can write it up as an answer — if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Than you , that looks interesting - Would you mind writing it as an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/78529/best-way-to-get-coordinates-of-each-node-of-a-way/78582) on the OSM help forum, you can use the [geometry operator](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Geometry) in a [convert statement](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#The_statement_convert) along with the `geom` [output argument](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#out).

Using the *way* ID in your question, the query would look like this:

```txt
[out:json];
way(5053100);
convert item ::=::,::geom=geom(),_osm_type=type();
out geom;
```

Here's an example in a runnable snippet:

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABMAplCALA8gNxQJwAcBDAZ1IClSEAKARxAIE8AuRUqfGMAcwEpEAbwBQiRPjQh8SVOgw0ARBihRCpFgHoNcPETKkAtMUIwAdABMUG4zA3coBQhIf4FAGiGixiAEZxzrIhgKADuiACqAEoAMgDKKMT4mAAKicQAtqQ0ANrZCubEUMTuiAzMALrlfG5eYuloGP5sCslYsQAq7l4AvnymUBgoYDQSpIgAvAB84iikpgBW1MN8fADcwt3CwhAIHKWM+EwTiAAGwtlwIFAsiwjl6yHETDQArAAMLwDMAIxvb2vbBC6KCIGAOdKIFgscZQtxQngoODpcYIpE0aoAfTgpHSGKgTEIKHG+MJ6PWlxBqPS6xO62EskwuEc+iotDKhz6AyGNB2YGoABsUKZ+XB+OsgA)

```js
function fetchOverpassJson(query) {
  return fetch("https://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter", {
    body: new URLSearchParams([["data", query]]),
    method: "POST",
  }).then(res => res.json());
}

const query = `
[out:json];
way(5053100);
convert item ::=::,::geom=geom(),_osm_type=type();
out geom;
`;

fetchOverpassJson(query).then(console.log);
```

And here's the static output of the code above at the time I ran the query:

```json
{
  "version": 0.6,
  "generator": "Overpass API 0.7.60 f4c14d41",
  "osm3s": {
    "timestamp_osm_base": "2023-04-23T14:58:09Z",
    "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL."
  },
  "elements": [
    {
      "type": "item",
      "id": 1,
      "geometry": {
        "type": "LineString",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            -110.5141282,
            31.9773252
          ],
          [
            -110.5123291,
            31.9766748
          ]
        ]
      },
      "tags": {
        "adot_name": "Tucson-Benson Highway",
        "bicycle": "yes",
        "hgv": "designated",
        "highway": "motorway",
        "lanes": "2",
        "maxspeed": "75 mph",
        "old_ref": "US 80 (old AZ 86)",
        "oneway": "yes",
        "ref": "I 10",
        "_osm_type": "way"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```